# What is the correct, programmatic way to identify if an Azure region supports a resource type fully in Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

Currently, I'm looking at using Front Door in an Azure resource group. When I look at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/global-infrastructure/services/?products=frontdoor&regions=all , it shows that this resource is in GA.

However, if I attempt to deploy a working, tested ARM template to certain regions I get an error which explictly indicates that the region is unsupported (this error message is from an Azure Devops pipeline, but I have seen the same error using powershell deployment ofthe same template with a params file locally):

[image]

As such, it doesn't seem like I can trust the availability by region site (and to be fair, it does have a disclaimer on it).

How do I tell, *before* a deployment is fired, whether I can safely use (i.e. deploy a specified resource type to) the region?

Ideally I'm looking for a dynamic solution to this, as just because a region isn't supported now doesn't mean it won't be in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use-`((Register-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Network).ResourceTypes | where-object ResourceTypeName -eq frontdoors).Locations`

which will provide list of locations

You can refer following link for more examples-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-supported-services#azure-powershell

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Interestingly, this returns: 
```global
Central US
East US
East US 2
North Central US
South Central US
West US
North Europe
West Europe
East Asia
Southeast Asia
Japan East
Japan West
Brazil South
Australia East
Australia Southeast``` , so I wonder if both global and a list of permitted locations is part of the issue here.